# Magento 2 custom module admin grid never loads

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid

I'm trying to write a custom module, wich needs grid in admin.I've tried 3 or four manuals but my grig never loads. It's allways showing a spinner.

[image: Screenshot]
Here is my code:
`app/code/Netzexpert/SatelliteOperators/Controller/Adminhtml/Operators/Index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Netzexpert\SatelliteOperators\Controller\Adminhtml\Operators;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Netzexpert_SatelliteOperators::operators');
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Operators'), __('Operators'));
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Manage Operators'), __('Manage Operators'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Operators'));

        return $resultPage;
    }

    /**
     * Is the user allowed to view the operators grid.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Netzexpert_SatelliteOperators::operators');
    }


}
```

`app/code/Netzexpert/SatelliteOperators/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="OperatorGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="OperatorGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Netzexpert\SatelliteOperators\Model\ResourceModel\Operator\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">OperatorGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Netzexpert\SatelliteOperators\Model\ResourceModel\Operator\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">netzexpert_satelliteoperators</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Netzexpert\SatelliteOperators\Model\ResourceModel\Operator</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="satelliteoperators_operator_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Netzexpert\SatelliteOperators\Model\ResourceModel\Operator\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

`Netzexpert/SatelliteOperators/view/adminhtml/ui_component/satelliteoperators_operators_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operators_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Operator</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="satelliteoperators_operator_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">OperatorGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                        <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operators_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <container name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operators_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </container>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/search/search</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operators_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operators_columns.${ $.index }.visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterRange name="id">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                        <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <filterInput name="from">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">from</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">from</item>
                            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </filterInput>
                <filterInput name="to">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">to</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">to</item>
                            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </filterInput>
            </filterRange>
            <filterInput name="name">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput>
            <filterSelect name="status">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                        <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select...</item>
                        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="disable" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Active</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="enable" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Deactive</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operators_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operators_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="satelliteoperators/operators/massDelete"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operators_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">20</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="30" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">30</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="50" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">50</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="100" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">100</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="200" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">200</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="satelliteoperators_operators_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operators_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">satelliteoperators_operator_listing.satelliteoperators_operator_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">IDs</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="stylecolor">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Style Color</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="textcolor">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Text Color</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Netzexpert\SatelliteOperators\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\OperatorActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Magento 2.0 or 2.1?

Comment: Use this https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule. It works fine

Comment: It is Magento 2.1.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only issue with below file & spelling mistake

**Netzexpert/SatelliteOperators/view/adminhtml/ui_component/satelliteoperators_operators_listing.xml**

Replace `satelliteoperators_operator_listing` with

```
satelliteoperators_operators_listing
```

Due to spelling mistake it occurs.

Please also check database field name.

Comment: You are the best!

Comment: @Styopchik No one will best. It's learning process. You will learn from your mistakes. That's it. But keep in mind don't repeat same mistake again. :)